# Where to put the continue statement in C?

Tags: c

The problem is that this code output stop at 21, it doesn't continue to 23.
my expected output would be: 11 12 13 21 23 31 32 33

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int a=1,b=1;
    
    while(a<=3)
    {
        b=1;
        while(b<=3)
        {   
            if(a==2&&b==2)
            continue;
            printf("%d%d\n",a,b);
            b++;
        }
    a++;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As you do not tell us what you expect your code to do, we cannot tell you how to fix it. Please provide expected behaviour showing expected output.

Comment: "so I challenged myself " so you challenged yourself to ask for solution here? Obviously unlike `for` loop `continue` in your code skips variable `b` increment.

Comment: Also, please do not spam with multiple unrelated language tags. There is no Python involved here. And C and C++ are very different languages as well

Comment: `if (a==2&&b==2)`, then you `continue` the `while` loop without updating `a` or `b`. The result is an infinite loop.

Comment: Recommendation: Adhere to an [indentation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style). Bugs are often often visible as irregularities in code, so if you force the code into a regular form, the irregularities stand out more. Feel free to forge your own. I use something very similar to [Allman style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style)  because I've found it makes whole families of bugs obvious or impossible.

Comment: you may want `if (~(a == 2 && b == 2)) printf("%d%d\n", a, b);` and get rid of the `continue;` statement... or `if (a != 2 || b !=2)`

Comment: One of the best programmer productivity-improving tools you're ever likely to find is the debugger.  With a debugger you can step through problem areas in your code line by line (or instruction by instruction if you need that resolution) and see exactly what your code does. Assumptions that you made while writing the code are probably carried through to your debugging. The debugger doesn't give a smurf about your assumptions. It just shows you what is. As soon as you see something you didn't expect, like a wrong value stored or a wrong path taken, stop and examine closely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not continuing after a == 2 and b == 2 because before incrementing b to 3 the contninue statement gets executed.
Either move it before if statement like.
[but for this you need to start b from 0 (b=0) and check for "while(b < 3)"]:

```
++b;
if (a == 2 && b == 2){
    continue;
}
```

or:

```
while(b<=3){   
  if(a == 2 && b == 2){
    ++b;
    continue;
  }
  printf(...);
  ++b;
}
```